# gnus to send html-formatted emails

Tags: gnus, html, org-mime

I'm trying to send an html-formatted email via gnus. I found this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/nZBJxHHYdko

which suggests:

```
1. M-x mml-insert-part enter
2. Content type: text/html
```

I tried this as shown in the screenshot:

[image]
but got a plaintext email (on an android gmail client).

What is the proper way to do it or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should add that I'm not looking for a discussion on whether html emails are evil or not, like into what the linked google groups thread devolved

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this subject, but my instinct says the `xhtml` content should fall between the `<#part ...>` and `<#/part>` MML tags inserted by `mml-insert-part`.

Comment: that was it, tt may seems obvious but other solutions I tried (and that did work, like this: http://www.tokiwinter.com/gnu-unix-commands-sending-html-formatted-email-command-line/) seem to work by setting a global "interpret content as html" flag, so was thinking in those terms. nice to be able to mix html and plaintext. @Basil could you add as an answer?

Comment: I'm new to this community, but the consensus amonst moderators seems to be in favour of closing questions which revolve around simple user errors like this one. I'll make an answer out of my comment just in case, but you may want to consider closing the question.

Comment: If you use org-mode, you can use [org-mime](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-mime.html). This converts your text into a multipart message; one HTML, one plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your problem is a simple syntax error: the `xhtml` content in question should be placed within the `<#part ...>` `<#/part>` tag pair inserted by `mml-insert-part` in order to be interpreted as anything other than plaintext.